# How to see if process is "non-responsive"?

Tags: process

Is there a way to check in Terminal if certain process (known PID) is doing something or is non-responsive and has "hang"? Using Ubuntu 14.04 and processes in question are TestDisk and GParted.

Answer (score 3):

you can check diskIO and cpu usage of those processes. it wont give a definitive answer but it will show you if the process is busy.

```
sudo iotop | grep [your pid here]
top | grep [your pid here]
```